# Using deployer in windows 10, There are no commands defined in the "C" namespace

Tags: php, windows, php-deployer

got deployer set up in my user directory, so from that location I access deployer via this cmd:

```
call vendor/bin/dep
```

I have a deploy.php config file located in project directory. When I run the following cmd, the error follows:

```
C:\Users\>call vendor/bin/dep -f C:\wamp64\www\project\trunk\deploy.php deploy test


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "C" namespace.
```

This is my first time using Deployer. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

So I missed this one line in installing, I should of installed Deployer in the project directory that I want to upload. So going to the location of the deployer.php config file I installed deployer using composer.

> composer require deployer/deployer